# Unix & Linux is the best place for ask about how working some thing in Linux or what is the purpose of a file of linux?

Tags: discussion

Before I ask in the main site of Unix & Linux I would like know what is the best place for ask this kind of question, specifically if a user wants to know how something works in Linux or what is its use in Linux.

For example if I'm not sure how this file from Linux (Ubuntu), if I `cd` into `/dev` (ubuntu) and I see this file: `hugepages` and its documentation is hard to understand, should I ask how this file works here?

If not on this site, where can I direct this type of question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi and welcome to U&L.

Before posting your question it's best to familiarize yourself with our documentation on what types of questions are on topic and which are not:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Questions that purely ask for reference or learning material are off-topic. This is the close reason, that we'll typically use for questions that fall into that category:

> Requests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic. The only exception is questions about where to find official documentation (e.g. POSIX specifications). See the Help Center and our Community Meta for more information.

It's best to be specific and try and ask questions that will result in a absolute answer. A good question should result in 1-2 answers max. There are exceptions but this is a general rule.

Regarding your question about `hugepages` that would be a on-topic question, IMO.

Always try and search before asking a question. We have a pretty extensive collection of questions + answers so it's likely the case that we may already have many of your questions answered.

If you find a question where the answers do not make sense or there are specifics that you do not grasp, ask follow-up questions.

Good luck.